# Java installation error on ubuntu 16.04 server edision

Tags: 16.04, java

How can I proceed further to install java

Environment: 16.04 Server Edision

test@ubuntu:~$ java -version

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

Comment: Did you read that error? It is not installed run `sudo apt install default-jre`

Comment: Getting this error if i run that

Comment: Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1
  403  Forbidden
59% [Working]
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1
  403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-m

Comment: Please try to read the errors, run `sudo apt update`

Comment: Update doesn't show any error

Comment: test@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Fetched 94.5 kB in 57s (1,636 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: Now you have updated successfully, run `sudo apt install default-jre`

Comment: Same error! i'm seeing the above which I pasted.  Err:1 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded Tar jdk and updated the java path

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java 1
```

Not it showing java version.

```
test@ubuntu:~/elasticsearch-2.3.4$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```